How to compare multiple cells data with multiple columns using python
I have an excel with some data like below image.enter image description here  If you compare column A and column B WITH column D and E(A1,B1 present in D and E and A3,B3 present in D,E...) so these two will true and other is false, how to write code in python
I can see only row comparison, now looking for cell to column comparison like(A1,B1 has to compare column D,E and repeat this by increasing A2, A3.....
Sample Excel Data:
enter image description here
Comparison between excel multiple cells data with multiple columns without knowing cells limit.

I have come up with 3 different ways that you can approach this. My only query is that you did not highlight the combination of 10 & 400 which are in both A & B and D & E. Thus my answers include this so im not sure if this is what you want.
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
    'B':[100,900,300,600,500,900,1000,700,200,400],
    'C':[6,2,7,9,3,1,8,10,4,5],
    'D':[800,400,1000,100,300,100,600,400,600,500]
})

# Method 1 - this converts column A & B into a tuple and compares to 
# a tuple of C & D
df['new_column_1'] = (df[['A', 'B']].apply(tuple, axis=1)
                    .isin(df[['C', 'D']].apply(tuple, axis=1)))

# Method 2 - this utilizes numpy which can often be faster
df['new_column_2'] = np.any((df['A'].values[:, None] == df['C'].values) & (df['B'].values[:, None] == df['D'].values), axis=1)

# Method 3 - this utilizes pandas merge function 
merged_df = df.merge(df, left_on=['A', 'B'], right_on=['C', 'D'], how='left', indicator=True)
df['new_column_3'] = merged_df['_merge'] == 'both'
df

The output gives me:

I forgot to mention that if you would like to have the new column placed in between the columns then you could assign any of the methods you choose to a variable first and then insert this whereever you would like it placed.
For example, if we choose method 1, instead of directly assigning this as a column and placing it at the end of the dataframe, we can do:
# this places the results into a variable first
new_col = (df[['A', 'B']].apply(tuple, axis=1).isin(df[['C', 'D']].apply(tuple, axis=1)))

# insert the column at index position 2 (since indexing begins at zero)
df.insert(loc=2, column='New_Column', value=new_col)


Can we use same code for string tuple comparison?

yes this will work if they are strings or integers. the pair of columns are combined into a tuple pair which is then checked against the tuple pairs from the other columns. However, this will not work if, for example, column A are integers and column C are strings. the columns being compared must be of the same data type. So a string must be compared to another string and an integer must be compared to an integer.

getting error("expected string or bytes-like object") when I try like this: work_sheet['D'] = (work_sheet[['B', 'C']].apply(tuple, axis=1)
.isin(work_sheet[['F', 'G']].apply(tuple, axis=1))) and here work_sheet is the excel sheet name

can you provide a bit more info as to how the data is stored. Have you read in the excel data into a pandas dataframe?

I have two data bases and each database has multiple tables with different table names, structure and row count

I have two data bases and each database has multiple tables with different table names, structure and row count. now reading tables from each database and writing into excel using different sheets (table name and row count is sheet1, table name and stricture is sheet2), now workbook has two sheet sheet1 has table names and row count, sheet2 has table name column name.

you will need to read in the excel data into a pandas dataframe in order to use the python code

Yes by using pandas data frame I read and write to excel, after write into excel need to compare: work_sheet['D'] = (work_sheet[['B','C']].apply(tuple, axis=3)
.isin(work_sheet[['F','G']].apply(tuple, axis=3))) or work_sheet['D{}'.format(row_num)] = '=COUNTIF(F$3:F$258,B{})>0'.format(row_num) +'=COUNTIF(G$3:G$258,C{})>0'.format(row_num) which is correct. Countif always getting "True" only and isin getting error "expected string or bytes-like object"

it appears you have combined python code with excel code so im not really sure if thats possible

You can do this with a single Excel formula as below:
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2:A11&B2:B11,D2:D11&E2:E11,0))



I think you should use Python/JavaScript. Using Machine Learning techniques by importing the Excel data as a CSV file you can easily do your required task.
